# Replace Tag of and xml file after pattern matching using shell

Tags: unix

I have an input xml file like below

INPUT FILE

```
<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Deep</entryName>
<Code>777</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>


<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Saurav</entryName>
<Code>666</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>


<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Ankur</entryName>
<Code>555</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>
```

I want to comment the tag  if i find the pattern "Total Deep" so that the output file looks like below

OUTPUT

```
<!--<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Deep</entryName>
<Code>777</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>-->


<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Saurav</entryName>
<Code>666</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>


<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Ankur</entryName>
<Code>555</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>
```

Since i am new to shell scripting, can anyone help me out as to how i can apply this with the help of shell scripting?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Be more specific about *if I find the pattern "Total Deep"*. Do you want to check if the string "Total Deep" occurs anywhere inside a `<ReconSummary>`...`</ReconSummary>` block? Or only in the `<entryName>` tag? As an exact match or as a substring? (e.g. `<entryName>Some Total Deep Stuff</entryName>`) Does the opening/closing tag pair `<entryName>` and `</entryName>` always occur in the same line? Are there always blank lines between `</ReconSummary>` and the next `<ReconSummary>`?

Comment: i want to check if the string "Total Deep" occurs anywhere inside a <ReconSummary>...</ReconSummary> block

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification. Don't use comments for this. And please answer all questions.

Comment: cross-posted on U&L https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/460009/deep-mukherjee?tab=questions

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution, its not pretty, but this likely won't be in any case unless you want to actually do meaningful XML parsing:

```
perl -0777 -e 'print s{.*<entryName>Total Deep</entryName>.*}{<!-- $& -->}sr, "\n\n" for split /\n\n/, <>' yourfile.xml
```

Most imporant: It requires what you show to be valid for future use, in this case sections must be split on at least two newlines!

Essentially:

1. Read in all the xml
2. split it on double newlines
3. Wrap the xml stub in comments if it contains said xml string
4. Print it back

Do you want to update the file as it is, or redirect this output to a new file?

And in a shellscript:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

thefile="$*"

newxml=`perl -0777 -e 'print s{.*<entryName>Total Deep</entryName>.*}{<!-- $& -->}sr, "\n\n" for split /\n\n/, <>' "$thefile"`

echo "$newxml" > "$thefile"
```

(create a text file with that content, make it executable, and run it like this: `yourscript.sh somefile.xml`)

Comment: sure, put that perl oneliner in a shell script

Comment: can you help me out with the shell scripting code?

Comment: Sure, I added a block of shell script code. You likely want to specify which xml file you want to work with - that is really a topic for another question, but you could do as shown above, it will work fine for a single file at a time. You should look into how to receive filename arguments to a shell script on your own first.

Comment: perl -0777 means?

Comment: Could you please tell me what the command is doing ? perl -0777 -e 'print s{.*<entryName>Total Deep</entryName>.*}{<!-- $& -->}sr, "\n\n" for split /\n\n/, <>'

Comment: It means perl will read all the file contents in one go, instead of line-by-line. Note I made several updates to the script block. should be fine now.
Also note this code works for xml exactly in the form you presented it. It does not handle well much variation to it. For example it will double-comment a file you have already processed.

Comment: `s{...}{...}` is perl code to perofrm regular expression with substitution. Essentially you tell it to look for the first block {...} and replace it with the second block {...}.  Regular expression is a topic for another day, but in this case it looks for that exact part of xml you mentioned, and it includes any characters before it and any characters after it (thats what `.*` does). The XML has already been split in chunks around double newlines, thats what `split /\n\n/` does

Comment: while read -r line do;
LineNum=`grep -n "Deep" Formula.xml | cut -d: -f 1`
TOTAL=`expr $LineNum + 9`
echo $LineNum
echo $TOTAL
done < file.txt My code is getting exception for expr it is showing expr: syntax error. can anyone suggest on this?

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="<ReconSummary>" } $0 ~ "<entryName>Total Deep</entryName>" { gsub("\n<entryName>","<entryName>",$0);print "<!--<ReconSummary>";gsub("</ReconSummary>","</ReconSummary>-->",$0);print $0;next } { gsub("\n<entryName>","<entryName>",$0);print "<ReconSummary>";print $0 }' file
```

Explanation:

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
             RS="<ReconSummary>"                                           # Set the record separator to "ReconSummary>"
           } 
     $0 ~ "<entryName>Total Deep</entryName>" {                            # Process where we have a match for "..Totakl Deep.." in the record
             gsub("\n<entryName>","<entryName>",$0);                       # Remove any blank lines above "<entryName>"
             print "<!--<ReconSummary>";                                   # Print the amended record separator
             gsub("</ReconSummary>","</ReconSummary>-->",$0);              # Amend the end record separator
             print $0;                                                     # Print the record
             next                                                          # Skip to the next record
            } 
            { 
             gsub("\n<entryName>","<entryName>",$0);                       # When processing none matching records, remove the blank line above "<entryName>"
             print "<ReconSummary>";                                       # Print the recrtod separator
             print $0                                                      # Print the line
            }' file
```